# How to average out value returned by an instance method for collection?

Tags: ruby, integer, instance, average

I have a simple method inside a model:

```
def term_months
  ((started_at - injected_at) / 1.month).to_i
end
```

This returns a simple integer.

In my View, I have a collection of this model type and I want to average out the results of each model's `term_months` value.

If this were a column, I could use something like `@terms.average(:term_months)`, but this isn't the case.

Is there some way to average them out inline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You 'll have to do it manually with a map:

```
@terms.map(&:term_months).inject(:+).to_f / @terms.length
```

What you can do is define that as a class method on `Term`

```
def self.average_term_months
  scoped.map(&:term_months).inject(:+).to_f / scoped.length
end
```

and use it as `@terms.average_term_months`

This method is not for use as a classic class method, but more as a scope. However I do not define it as a scope because (personal taste here) I want scopes to be chainable.

Comment: The first bit works, but the second class method on Term doesn't. self.map would call it against a single Term instance correct? Not the actual collection.

Comment: @Serg - class methods works on the collection as well (assumin you have an ActiveRecord::Relation collection, not the array of models)

Comment: My @terms collection is just a simple `@terms = Term.order("created_at DESC")` - the second bit doesn't work.

Comment: @Serg - Order returns ActiveRecord::Relation, so it should work. What error do you get? Try changing `self` to `scoped`

Comment: @BroiSatse and serg you are right, I updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
@terms.sum(&:term_months).to_f / @terms.size
```

if `started_at` and `injected_at` are columns in your DB, then below would is possible has a better performance than using `Enumerable` methods (`:sum`) as it delegates the *averaging* to the DB and just returns an integer/float object then `term_months` would not be required:

```
Model.average("(started_at - injected_at)/ #{1.month}") #where Model is the name of your ActiveRecord Object
```

Comment: @bjhaid- It won't work, terms_month is not a column but a custom method.

Comment: @BroiSatse which wouldn't work `sum`in this case is [`Enumerable#sum`](http://apidock.com/rails/Enumerable/sum) and not the ActiveRecord sum, so it works on method calls

Comment: Enumerable sum first argument is identity, defaulted to 0, it cannot be symbol. Probably what you meant was `sum(&:term_months)`

Comment: Thanks, my bad missed the `&`, but the second option is the most ideal answer for the OP

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using the [quickstats gem](http://rubygems.org/gems/quickstats), which is designed to update basic statistics on an observation by observation basis as new observations become available. This can be very useful if the dataset is large and you just want the summary stats without having to retain all of the individual observations. Quickstats uses recurrence relationships `Xbar(n+1) <- f(Xbar(1), x_n)` and `s^2(n+1) <- g(s^2(n), x_n)`, where `Xbar(n)` and `s^2(n)` the average and sample variance, respectively, based on `n` observations; `x_n` is the n<sup>th</sup> observation; and `f` and `g` represent the appropriate update functions.